# Online PDF viewer with permalinks on pages

Tags: web-apps, pdf-viewer, hosted, hyperlink

I need service where I could load my documents in the PDF format that there was an opportunity to deliver to permalink on each page.

For example, if my PDF document  locates at the address `example.com/mypdf`, on page 4 it would be possible to follow the link `example.com/mypdf#4`, on page 14 — `example.com/mypdf#14` and so on.

I tried Zoho Docs, Google Drive, Dropbox, but on these services there is no possibility of permalink on pages.

Obligatory:

- Permalinks on any page of my documents,
- Free 1 GB or more for my documents,
- Unlimited period of storage of documents,
- Opportunity to share the document for any Internet user.

Desirable:

- Low load of RAM, that computers of users didn't hang when they opening PDF documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**GitHub**](https://github.com/) solved my problem. GitHub meets all my needs.

---

---

### 1. Settings

- [**https://github.com/KristinitaTest/KristinitaTest.github.io**](https://github.com/KristinitaTest/KristinitaTest.github.io) — my GitHub repository;
- [**https://github.com/KristinitaTest/KristinitaTest.github.io/blob/master/pdf/SashaVKontakte.pdf**](https://github.com/KristinitaTest/KristinitaTest.github.io/blob/master/pdf/SashaVKontakte.pdf) — my pdf file.

For example, we open in browser page number 4 of my pdf file.

[image: Page number 4]

---

---

### 2. Hyperlinks to specific pages

To create a hyperlink to a specific page of the document, [**we need add to the end of URL of PDF document**](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/can-i-hyperlink-specific-page-pdf-file):

> `#page=$number_of_page`

For example, `#page=7` or `#page=14`.

---

---

### 3. First solution — [**Jupyter nbviewer**](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/)

Insert URL to GitHub PDF document in input field — **https://github.com/KristinitaTest/KristinitaTest.github.io/blob/master/pdf/SashaVKontakte.pdf** for me, → add in end of URL number of desired page — `#page=4` for me, → click `Go!` → will be opened page

> **https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/KristinitaTest/KristinitaTest.github.io/blob/master/pdf/SashaVKontakte.pdf#page=4**

---

---

### 4. Second solution — [**GitHub Pages**](https://pages.github.com/)

[**Create in GitHub**](http://isizov.ru/github-kak-hosting-dlya-sajtov/) repository `$your_username.github.io`, for example, if my account `KristinitaTest`, I can to create only `KristinitaTest.github.io` repository, not `RandomName.github.io`. For one account we may to create [**only one GitHub Pages repository**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564009/5951529), name of repository must be identical your GitHub account name.

After creating a repository download in repository your PDF file and open in [**address bar**](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/addrebar.htm) of your browser `$your_username.github.io/$your_pdf_directory/$pdf_file_name.pdf#page=$number_of_page`, for me correct link is:

> **https://KristinitaTest.github.io/pdf/SashaVKontakte.pdf#page=4**